# how to make a jsonarray be a item source in React Native ListView?

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a stupid question, but i did not solve it for two hours. I use ListView in `react native`, `an item` is `ViewPager`. So I should get a JsonArray data to `ViewPager`.

```
      fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) =>{
        var topData = responseJson.top_data;
        var newData = responseJson.new_data;
        var dataList = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(topData); // topData is a jsonarray, but i just want it be a Item data, how to do?
        this.setState({
          dataSource: dataList,
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        let message = error.message;
      });
    }
```

------------update in 22/2/2017, solve it--------------

```
        var topData = responseJson.top_data;
        var data = {topData : topData}
        var dataList = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data);
```

Comment: What you mean by `i just want it be a Item data`?  all data from `topData`will be passed to each item of the listview, and you can render any needed part.

Comment: @Ataomega i want `topData` only use in one `Component`, i use `cloneWithRows` it will be many item.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you mean.